# Does Soul Tear shout affect conjurations?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I've heard that the soul tear shout is pretty rad, but it also resurrects the enemy if it dies. Will this resurrection affect my conjurations? If I have 2 thralls and soul tear someone, will one of my thralls die, or will I have 3 conjurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, Soul Torn enemies count toward your conjuration limit.**

Soul Tear will not let you exceed your 1- or 2-summon limit. While the damage and Soul Trap effects will work on summoned creatures, the reanimation effect will not work on targets immune to reanimation (e.g. summons). Note, however, that its effect is more powerful than even Dead Thrall, and thus *will* work on creatures such as giants and mammoths that are simply too powerful to be otherwise raised.

Creatures raised with Soul Tear will crumble to ash upon death or upon the end of the effect's duration (60 seconds) just like most reanimation effects; you cannot use Soul Tear to raise a corpse (I've tried), your target *must* be alive when you Shout.

Comment: So If I have 2 thralls, and I soul tear an enemy to death, what will happen?

Comment: @Crubleigh One of your thralls will crumble into ash, while the victim of your Soul Tear will rise as a new -- albeit short-lived -- minion.